# Как сделать переход на новый фрагмент из RecyclerView при помощи navigation?

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, navigation

Есть фрагмент с recycle, нужно чтобы при нажатии на какой-либо элемент открывался новый фрагмент, я не особо понимаю как это сделать с navigation

MainFragment.kt

```
class MainFragment: Fragment() {
private var _binding: FragmentMainBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!


//  private var binding: FragmentMainBinding? = null
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {


    _binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root
    return view
  //  val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
    //return rootView

//    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)?.also {
     //   binding = FragmentMainBinding.bind(it)
      //      }

}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding?.recyclerView?.adapter = RecycleAdapter(fillList())
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    binding?.pickDateBtn?.setOnClickListener {
        val dpd = DatePickerDialog(requireContext(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{ view: DatePicker?, mYear: Int, mMonth: Int, dayOfMonth: Int ->
            binding?.pickDateBtn?.setText("" + dayOfMonth + "." + (mMonth+1) + "." + mYear)}, year,month,day)
        dpd.show()
    }



    }

override fun onDestroyView(){
    _binding = null
    super.onDestroyView()
}

private fun fillList(): List<String> {
    val data = mutableListOf<String>()
    (0..30).forEach { i -> data.add("$i element") }
    return data
}


}
```

RecycleAdapter.kt

```
class RecycleAdapter(private val names: List<String>):
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.MyViewHolder>(){

class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var textViewUp: TextView? = null
    var textViewDown: TextView? = null

    init {
        textViewUp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUp)
        textViewDown = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDown)
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycleview_item, parent, false)
    return MyViewHolder(itemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.textViewDown?.text = names[position]
    holder.textViewUp?.text = "РУБЛЬ"
}

override fun getItemCount() = names.size}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь есть два варианта. Используйте один из них.

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{ view -> 
    view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action)
}
```

Или

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.action))
```

Comment: В обоих способах при нажатии на элемент приложение вылетает, из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: вы не могли бы посмотреть ошибку в LogCat?

Comment: все, решил проблему
надо было пару лишних строк убрать просто, которые не нужны были
спасибо)